# How would I parse a file (which seperates unicode text with 00 bytes) into a list?

Tags: c#

Given a selection of bytes in a hex editor shows the file separates text with 00 bytes, it's a coloring file, with the material name, follolwed by a 3 byte hex code that determines colour. which is why it contains bytes like FF. the bytes are shown like this:

```
00 11 46 6F 6C 69 61 67 65 5F 45 76 65 72 67 72 65 65 6E 00 FF FF FF 00 0D 46 6F 6C 69 61 67 65 5F 42 69 72 63 68 00 80 A7 55
```

which translates into ascii as such:

```
Foliage_Evergreen�ÿÿÿ�
Foliage_Birch�€§U
```

How would I separate these bytes down into a list and convert them into text list of the bytes' values? I'm having trouble understanding how I'd go about doing it... this is what I'm doing right now:

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
}
string line = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(line);
List<string> listtext = line.Split('.').ToList();
listBox1.DataSource = listtext;
```

Comment: This sounds like teh Null Byte/Terminator was used as seperator for a .CSV like structure. To properly parse the rest, you *must* know what encoding was used https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/. Asuming that is actually tet, I can exclude ASCII. Hex 11 is classed as "DC1", a control character. So this has to be 2 bytes/characer. Some form of unicode, propably?

Comment: It doesn't look like text to me, 11 is not a visible character, nor is FF, can you elaborate on the format here?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It could be one of the 2 Byte Unicode Encodings.  Maybe even one of those that chances the Number of bytes based on the Codepoint to encode? But yes, something does seem off.

Comment: Foliage_Evergreen translates to Hex 46 6f 6c 69 61 67 65 5f 45 76 65 72 67 72 65 65 6e | Foliage_Birch to 46 6f 6c 69 61 67 65 5f 42 69 72 63 68 So the first byte after the 00 is also not part of the ASCII. Maybe it is a counter/primary key of some sort?

Comment: The goal is still to view the ascii text in list format. So what I'm trying to do is isolate the text, and ignore the excess...

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn’t do that, will crash for some files with encoding exception:

```
string line = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(line);
```

Use `File.ReadAllBytes` instead, no need to read text then convert to bytes.

Then you’ll need to parse array of bytes into your records.

Based on your example data, your format uses 0 as field separator, and strings are prepended by their lengths. Here’s an example how to parse, untested:

```
static IEnumerable<(string, Color)> parse( byte[] data )
{
    for( int p = 0; p < data.Length; )
    {
        // '\0'
        if( 0 != data[ p++ ] ) throw new ApplicationException();
        // String length byte
        int length = data[ p++ ];
        // The string; assuming the encoding is UTF8
        string name = Encoding.UTF8.GetString( data, p, length );
        p += length;
        // '\0'
        if( 0 != data[ p++ ] ) throw new ApplicationException();
        // 3 color bytes, assuming the order is RGB
        Color color = Color.FromArgb( 0xFF, data[ p ], data[ p + 1 ], data[ p + 2 ] );
        p += 3;
        yield return (name, color);
    }
}
```

Comment: neither holds any data, tried writing both string and colour. neither has anything inside.

Comment: @PhoenixARCPlayz Use debugger, verify the input `byte[] data` argument contains the stuff you see in the hex editor. If it’s OK, might be a bug in my code, I haven’t tested it.